# Latest viable JDK for Grails 5.1.4?

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 5.1.4 for a number of projects now, and planning to move to 5.1.7 soon. I've been continuing to develop with Java 8 and deploy with Java 11, but I'm wondering whether there is a more recent version which I could be using without problems? The docs talk about the minimum JDK version required (8), but not the maximum usable one.

Comment: I think there are some issues with Apache Groovy 3, and Java 17 but you might be able to use it. It depends on the application. For now, I have not heard of any issues with Grails® framework 5 and Java 14.

Comment: Curiously Java 14 does not seem to be available via SDKMAN at all, which is the way I do this these days. I'll maybe experiment with getting a version of Groovy 3 which works with Java 17. If that fails, Java 11 will work fine.

Comment: Did you find out anything on grails 5, java compatibility?